# How to classify new sentences with unknown attributes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I'm trying to classify 30000 unlabeled sentences into 2 labels(for example, pos and neg) by using machine learning algorithms. To do this, I have chosen 100 positive sentences and 100 negative sentences as training sets. Then, I used SVM to train the 200 chosen sentences to create a trained model. Finally, classified the remaining 29800 unlabeled sentences with the trained model.

However, I believe that when the trained model classifies the remaining 29800 unlabeled sentences there must have been some unknown words that was not trained to the model I created. There might be sentence that does not include any words that have been trained and how can it be classified. The following code has classified the sentences using scikit.

```
import numpy as np
import data
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

data = data.Data()

allSent = data.getPosSent() + data.getNegSent()
stopWords = data.getStopwords()

Dataset_X = []
Dataset_Y = []

for meta, label in allSent:
   Dataset_X.append(meta)
   Dataset_Y.append(label)
X_train = np.array(Dataset_X)
Y_train = np.array(Dataset_Y)

classifier_SVC = Pipeline([
   ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
   ('classifier', SVC(kernel='rbf', C=10000000, gamma=1e-08))
   ])
classifier_SVC.fit(X_train, Y_train)

predSent = data.getPredSent()
predSentData = []
for i in range(len(predSent)):
   predSentData.append(predSent[i])
pred = np.array(predSentData)

for i in range(len(predSent)):
  print classifier_SVC.predict(pred)[i]
```

In conclusion, my question is

- How can a classifier classify a totally new sentence which means that the trained model have never seen any words contained in the new sentence.
- How many sentences do I need to train a model to say that it is enough? In other words, I have trained 200 but I do not know that it needs more data or not.

Comment: 200 sentences is not enough examples.

Comment: "It depends".  If all your samples are from a very constrained environment, just a few dozen may well be enough.  If every sample is a short sentence from a different domain (medicine, automotive, computing, handicrafts, etc etc) you may well need more than half, or even something like 90% for training.  Experiment and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Let us consider `y_i`, `x_i`, and `c_i` is `y`, `x` and weight of `i`-th support vector, respectively. For a given input z, we calculate `predict = sgn(sum(c_i*y_i*K(x_i,z))+b)` where b is a bias and `K` is a kernel( rbf kernel in your code). If `z` is a totally new sentence we obtain `predict = sgn(sum(c_i*y_i*exp(-gamma*x_i**2))*exp(-gamma*z**2)+b)`

2) It depend on your data. How about you check how many sentences cover how much % of words? Or if you have more than 200 labelled data, how about you evaluate a relations between the number of trained sentences and predicted scores?

Comment: From the first answer's predict formula, it is trying to give 'z' a influence to the predict value, but seems like it won't be that big of a difference. Thereby, predicting the new sentences by the features learned and cannot predict new sentences with new features. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is true.